# Obter valor TextBox dentro do Repeater com Javascript event Onchange

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Boa tarde, não estou conseguindo passar o valor de um `TextBox` `asp.net` criado dentro de um `Repeater` como parâmetro para uma função `javascript` evento `onchange`. Preciso passar dois parâmetros o primeiro é um `Eval("PostID")` ao qual funciona perfeitamente, mas o segundo parâmetro é o valor do próprio `TextBox` não consigo passa-lo. Alguém poderia passar um dica.

Imagem front-end:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="repeaterTable" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;">
                <div class="img-push">
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control input-sm"
                        placeholder="Pressione enter para postar comentário"
                        ID="txtPost" runat="server" 
                        onchange='<%# String.Format("FunctionComment(\"{0}\", "\{1}\");", 
                        Eval("PostID"), TextBoxAQUI) %> '>
                    </asp:TextBox>                    
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="repeaterTable" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;">
                <div class="img-push">
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control input-sm"
                        placeholder="Pressione enter para postar comentário"
                        ID="txtPost" runat="server" 
                        onchange='<%# String.Format("FunctionComment(\"{0}\", this.value);", 
                        Eval("PostID")) %> '>
                    </asp:TextBox>                    
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: não foi, o segundo parâmetro continua vazio. Já tentei this e this.value mas o valor do campo text não pega. Veja na nova imagem anexa.

Comment: testei novamente seu código agora foi sim! Obrigado